# Modifying the value in the dictionary python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key, key-value-store

I have a text file-turned-dictionary using itertools.

```
import itertools

plantfile = 'myplants.txt' #file path
plant = {} #create an empty dictionary
with open(plantfile, 'r') as f:
    for empty_line, group in itertools.groupby(f, lambda x: x == '\n'): 
        if empty_line:
            continue
        fruit, *desc = map(str.strip, group)
        plant[fruit] = desc
```

The result is:

```
{'banana' : ['delicious', 'yellow'],

'watermelon' : ['big', 'red'],

'orange' : ['juicy', 'vitamin c']}
```

I would like to prompt the user the name of the fruit (key) to modify both the key and description (value) or delete the whole record. It would be the best if I can use def () function.

The following are my current codes. They do not return me any error messages, however, they are also not reflected back in the dictionary file.

```
    print("What do you want to do with this database?
    1. Modify fruit information
    2. Delete fruit record")
    
    choice == input("Please enter your choice in number: ")
    
    while True:
        try:
            if choice == '1':
               original_name = input("What is the fruit name you would like to modify?").upper()
               new_name = input("What is the new fruit name?")
            
               with open(file, 'r+') as f: 
               string = f.read() 
               string = string.replace(original_name, new_name) 
               f.truncate(0) 
               f.seek(0) 
               f.write(string) #writeback to file
               print(f"You have modified {original_name} to {new_name}.")
               break
            else:
               delname = input("Please enter the name of the fruit: \n").upper() 
               delname = dict(filter(lambda item: delname in item[0], plant.items())) 
               break
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid input. Please try again.")
```

I can't figure out how to modify the values and it seems like the above code to modify the name of the key isn't working either.

The code above to delete the whole record is also not being reflected in the original file.

for eg, I would like to change the value of watermelon from 'big' to 'hard' and wishes to delete the whole record of banana.

```
{'watermelon' : ['hard', 'red'],
    
    'orange' : ['juicy', 'vitamin c']}
```

Please help me out. Thank you

Comment: Please provide  the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  You ask a question about modifying a dict, but most of your code seems concerned with the mechanics of file handling.  Please reduce your question to the problem area.

Comment: Are you trying to maintain a dict, or a text file?  You seem to be confused.  If this data is, indeed, in a text file, then why are you using the overhead of dict format?  Did you intend to make this a JSON file?  If so, you should use the `json` package.

Comment: Most of all, it appears that you're trying to use a text file (sequential character data) as if it were a data store in memory.  This is a clumsy mapping, which is why you're having trouble.  (1) Read the data store into a convenient data structure.  (2) Make the requested changes.  (3) Write the data store back to the file.

Comment: Sorry! It's my bad. I forgot to include my earlier parts of the codes. The dictionary I've mentioned is actually converted from a the text file

Comment: In which case, it seems immaterial to your question.  Again, please provide the expected MRE.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], emphasis on *reproducible* (but still mind *minimal*). The question currently includes only an assortment of incomplete code snippets, none of which can be run. If you are just wondering how to modify a dict *in-memory*, please remove the file-handling. If you are actually inquiring how to modify the *stored file*, please include a sample input file as well. Be mindful that various parts of the snippets, such as loop-less ``break`` and undefined name ``file``, make it impossible to run the code. Either remove them completely or add the required context.

Comment: Take note that manually seeking and truncating a file is generally *not* sensible. In most cases, opening the file for reading, closing it and opening it again for writing is more robust and easier to maintain.

Comment: I've edited the complete code in my question. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

Comment: See the answer by @sotmot for what is likely the issue. Note that such errors are less likely to slip through undetected when using the actual methods of the datastructure – for example, ``del plant[delname]`` instead of ``dict(filter(...))`` will throw a ``KeyError`` for invalid keys.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is for the question before the edit. There was an `.upper()` in the `original_name` input taken previously. The modified code is as follows:

```
import itertools

file = 'file.txt' 
plant = {} 
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for empty_line, group in itertools.groupby(f, lambda x: x == '\n'): 
        if empty_line:
            continue
        fruit, *desc = map(str.strip, group)
        plant[fruit] = desc

print(plant)


original_name = input("What is the fruit name you would like to modify?")
new_name = input("What is the new fruit name?")
    
with open(file, 'r+') as f: 
    string = f.read()
    string = string.replace(original_name, new_name) 
    f.seek(0) 
    f.write(string) #writeback to file
print(f"You have modified {original_name} to {new_name}.")
```

Assuming your `file.txt` looks like this:

```
banana
delicious, yellow

watermelon
big, red

orange
juicy, vitamin cc
```